# Why is $E[X|X+Y] = E[Y |X+Y]$ if X,Y are i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-integral, conditional-expectation

In proof of the fact that $E[X|X+Y] = \frac{X+Y}{2}$ when $X,Y$ are independent, identically distributed random variables, one uses the observation that $E[X|X+Y] = E[Y|X+Y]$ but I don't see why this is the case. Is there an easy proof of this statement?

Comment: Simply by symmetry.

Comment: @Vercingetorix For me this reasoning is too loose… by the same "argument" one could argue that $X = E[X|X] = E[Y|Y] = Y$ what's not true, obviosuly… and I did nothing else then "interchange" $X$ and $Y$… so one need a little bit more reasoning on that.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer.** This essentially boils down to the fact that

$$ \mathbf{E}[X \mid X+Y = z] = \mathbf{E}[Y \mid X+Y = z], $$

which is true because

1. both of the conditional expectations depend only on the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ (rather than on how the random vector $(X, Y)$ is realized), and
2. the role of $X$ and $Y$ in their joint distribution can be swapped without changing the joint distribution itself, i.e., the distribution is *exchangeable*.

---

**Longer answer.** Rigorously establishing the above equality in full generality requires the notion of regular conditional probability. So, let us tackle the original equality directly.

Let $\mu(\cdot) = \mathbf{P}(X \in \cdot)$ be the distribution of $X$. As usual, we will impose the condition that $\mu$ has finite first moment, i.e., $\int |x| \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) < \infty$.

Now let $\varphi(\cdot)$ be any bounded Borel-measurable function. Then by the change of variables formula (a.k.a. LOTUS), together with the fact that the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is the product measure $\mu \otimes \mu$, we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[X \varphi(X+Y)]
&= \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} x \varphi(x+y) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)\mu(\mathrm{d}y), \\
\mathbf{E}[Y \varphi(X+Y)]&= \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} y \varphi(x+y) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)\mu(\mathrm{d}y).
\end{align*}

By the Fubini's Theorem, these two integrals coincide. Since this is true for any $\varphi$, the uniqueness of conditional distribution implies that

$$ \mathbf{E}[X \mid X+Y] = \mathbf{E}[Y \mid X+Y] $$

holds $\mathbf{P}$-a.s. as required.

Comment: Hello @SangchulLee, where can I find a reference for that characterization of conditional expectation? I am sure I have seen it somewhere

Comment: @Snoop, I am pretty sure you have seen this, but I don't have a reference. It is rather a direct application of the definition once we restrict the class of $\varphi$ to indicator functions. That is, if $$\mathbf{E}[X\mathbf{1}_{\{X+Y\in B\}}] = \mathbf{E}[Y\mathbf{1}_{\{X+Y\in B\}}] $$ holds for any Borel $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then the corresponding conditional expectations (given $X+Y$) must coincide a.s.

Comment: @SangchulLee You gave expressions of $E[X\varphi(X + Y)]$ and $E[Y\varphi(X + Y)]$ respectively.  However, you haven't shown they are identical, right?

Comment: @Zhanxiong the only unwritten step is Fubini

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, that's my point.  It should be written out explicitly, where the i.i.d. assumption is formally put into use. In addition, I think Sangchul Lee's reply to Snoop should also be merged into the answer, which should make the whole argument more coherent.  This is because ultimately the goal is to show $E[X\varphi(X + Y)] = E[Y\varphi(X + Y)]$ rather than how they were expressed respectively.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Well my point is that you could have said *that* more explicitly :) so that even if Sangchul doesn't agree others can see it

Comment: @CalvinKhor Actually I did mention Fubini's theorem should be applied explicitly in a reply to another member.  But as later he deleted his comment, so I removed mine too.  Anyway, I think this conversation is fairly complete now to your point!

Comment: @Zhanxiong, You are absolutely correct. The fact that the two integrals coincide needs an explanation and I should have clarified that. Thank you, I updated my answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 3):

As both $E(X|X + Y)$ and $E(Y|X + Y)$ are $\sigma(X + Y)$-measurable, by the measure-theoretic definition of conditional expectation, it suffices to show that for any $G \in \sigma(X + Y)$, it holds that
\begin{align*}
\int_G X dP = \int_G E(Y|X + Y)dP. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Using the conditional expectation definition again, the right-hand side of $(1)$ is simply $\int_G Y dP$.  Therefore it suffices to show for any $G \in \sigma(X + Y)$,
\begin{align*}
\int_G X dP = \int_G Y dP. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Since (see *Probability and Measure*, Theorem 20.1) the $\sigma$-field $\sigma(X + Y)$ consists exactly of the sets $(X + Y)^{-1}(H) = \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) + Y(\omega) \in H\}$ for $H \in \mathscr{R}^1$, it suffices to show $(2)$ for $G = (X + Y)^{-1}(H), H \in \mathscr{R}^1$.  By assumption, $X$ and $Y$ are independent so that $(X, Y)$ has product measure  $\pi := \mu \times \mu$, where $\mu$ is the common distribution of $X$ and $Y$. It then follows by the change of variable theorem (*Probability and Measure*, Theorem 16.13) that
\begin{align}
\int_G X dP &= \int_\Omega X(\omega)I_{(X + Y)^{-1}(H)}(\omega)P(d\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} X(\omega)I_H((X + Y)(\omega))P(d\omega) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} xI_H(x + y)\pi(d(x, y)), \tag{3} \\  
\int_G Y dP &= \int_\Omega Y(\omega)I_{(X + Y)^{-1}(H)}(\omega)P(d\omega) =
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} Y(\omega)I_H((X + Y)(\omega))P(d\omega) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} yI_H(x + y)\pi(d(x, y)). \tag{4}
\end{align}

By Fubini's Theorem, the right-hand sides of $(3)$ and $(4)$ are respectively (where $H - x$ stands for the set $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^1: x + y \in H\}$):
\begin{align}
& \int_{\mathbb{R}^1}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}xI_H(x + y)\mu(dy)\right]\mu(dx) = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}x\mu(H - x)\mu(dx), \tag{5} \\  
& \int_{\mathbb{R}^1}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}yI_H(x + y)\mu(dx)\right]\mu(dy) = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}y\mu(H - y)\mu(dy). \tag{6}
\end{align}

The right-hand sides of $(5)$ and $(6)$ are evidently identical (in that both "$x$" and "$y$" may be viewed as dummy integrating variables).  Therefore, $(2)$ holds.  This completes the proof.

---

To appreciate that both of the independence assumption and the identical distribution condition are essential for $(2)$ to hold (thus to ensure $E[X | X + Y] = E[Y | X + Y]$ to hold), it may be helpful to give an example showing that $(2)$ needs not to hold when $X, Y$ are identically distributed but not independent (the other case, that $(2)$ needs not to hold when $X$ and $Y$ are independent but not identically distributed is trivial).  Consider the discrete joint distribution of $(X, Y)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{c | c c c}
       & Y = -1      & Y = 0        & Y = 1        \\ \hline
X = -1 & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9}  & 0            \\
X =  0 & 0           & \frac{1}{18} & \frac{5}{18} \\
X =  1 & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{18} & \frac{1}{18} 
\end{array}
\end{align}
It is straightforward to verify that $P[X = i] = P[Y = i] = 1/3, i = -1, 0, 1$, i.e., $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed.  On the other hand, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, as $P[X = 0, Y = 0] = \frac{1}{18} \neq P[X = 0]P[Y = 0] = \frac{1}{9}$.  Take $G = (X + Y)^{-1}(\{-1\})$, then
\begin{align}
\int_G X dP = -P[X = -1, Y = 0] = -\frac{2}{9} \neq 
\int_G Y dP = -P[X = 0, Y = -1] = 0.
\end{align}
Therefore, the independence assumption is crucial here.

Comment: My answer shows that we only need $(X, Y) \overset{d}{=} (Y, X)$. Independence is not necessary for this. They only need to be exchangeable.

Comment: @JasonSwanson I agree. I will modify my answer later accordingly when I get more time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer really is, "by symmetry", but the key is to note that the symmetry leaves the condition unchanged. It works because $X+Y=Y+X$. We cannot make the same "argument" to prove that $E[X\mid X]=E[Y\mid Y]$, because in this case, the condition has changed.

More rigorously, let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be measurable and assume $g(X,Y) = g(Y,X)$. Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be measurable. Then
\begin{align*}
  E[E[f(Y,X) \mid g(X,Y)]\,1_{\{g(X,Y)\in A\}}]
    &= E[E[f(Y,X)\,1_{\{g(X,Y)\in A\}} \mid g(X,Y)]]\\
    &= E[f(Y,X)\,1_{\{g(X,Y)\in A\}}]\\
    &= E[f(X,Y)\,1_{\{g(X,Y)\in A\}}],
\end{align*}
where in the last equality we use the fact that $(X,Y)\overset{d}{=}(Y,X)$ and $g(Y,X)=g(X,Y)$. Since $E[f(Y,X) \mid g(X,Y)]$ is $\sigma(g(X,Y))$-measurable, this shows that
$$
  E[f(Y,X) \mid g(X,Y)] = E[f(X,Y) \mid g(X,Y)].
$$

Answer (score -2):

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are defined over domain $\mathcal A$. Start with the definition of expectation with either expression. For example:

$$\mathbb E(X|X+Y=t) = \frac{\sum_{z \in\mathcal A} zP(X=z)P(Y = t-z)}{P(X+Y=t)}$$

If $X$ takes on value $z$, then $Y$ must take on value $t-z$ so that their sum is a constant, i.e., $X+Y = t$

Because $X$ and $Y$ are iid, $P(X=a) = P(Y=a), \forall a \in \mathcal A$. So we can replace the expression in the numerator above:
$$\sum_{z \in\mathcal A} zP(X=z)P(Y = t-z)= \sum_{z \in\mathcal A} zP(Y=z)P(X = t-z)$$
The expression on the right hand side is the definition of the expectation:
$$\mathbb E(Y|X+Y=t) = \frac{\sum_{z \in\mathcal A} zP(Y=z)P(X = t-z)}{P(X+Y=t)}$$

Comment: For those downvoting - why is this wrong?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because your expressions assume the random variables are discrete rather than dealing more generally.

Comment: OP did ask for an easy proof. I don't see why the same strategy wouldn't work for continuous RVs (replacing $P$ with $f$ and summation with integration)

Comment: Note that "easy proof" and "proof of subcase" are not synonyms.  Additionally, "I don't see why not" isn't a good defense in mathematics... try to write such a proof for absolutely continuous random variables and you'll see some problems with your analogy.  In the end, however, that's just another subcase, and if you want to chase subcases around, you'd have to also make such a proof for continuous singular distributions and the convex combinations of all such distributions.  In the end, I can't see how you would propose doing so without forgetting all that and working in the general context.

Comment: (+1) nice, intuitive answer athough not complete

Comment: There absolutely no problem with your answer.